# How to sort list of dict values based on their boolean values?

Tags: ansible

Using Linux server with installed versions of ansible 2.7.5 .

I was trying to sort the values based on their boolean values but unable to get the exact output.

Could anyone please help on the below request.

With the code,which I have tried either I'm able to fetch true values or false values but not combinely.

The below mentioned one is the list of dict values.

```
[{u'EDP130': True}, {u'EDP134': False}, {u'EDP136': False}, {u'EDP139': True}]
```

From the above mentioned list of dict I want to fetch the list of values like below.

Here, the values should come like pair of true and false.

```
[EDP130,EDP134,EDP139,EDP136]
```

Comment: You want to sort like True, False, True, False ? Is there any condition on the numerical value of EDP ?

Comment: Yes, want to sort like True, False, True, False.
There is no condition on the numerical values of EDP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting position in the list by a dict

```
b={
True:0,
False:1
}
d=[{u'EDP130': True}, {u'EDP134': False}, {u'EDP136': False}, {u'EDP139': True}]
l=[None]*len(d)
for i in d:
    for k,v in i.items():
        l[b[v]]=k
        b[v]+=2
print(l)
```

Comment: Hi Manoj,
Could I get more simplified code in ansible using bool filter.